# Not understanding why I can't access property in array of objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

When I declare an array of objects, where an an object can be two different types, where one type contains the value I want to get to and the other type does not, how can I access the type when it exists?

That is, I want to iterate through my `items` array and print out title when it exists, and otherwise, either skip the record or print out something like "title does not exist".

Here is the code with the forEach at the bottom.

```
    enum TabItemType {
    Dashboard = "DASHBOARD",
    SolarEnergy = "SOLARENERGY",
    PowerUsage = "POWERUSAGE",
    RateTabe = "RATETABLE",
    Profile = "PROFILE",
    Info = "INFO",
    }

    type ItemType = {separator: boolean } |  {
    name: TabItemType; title: string; icon: string; selected?: boolean
    }

    const items: Array<ItemType> = [
    {
        name: TabItemType.Dashboard,
        title: "Dashboard",
        icon: "k-i-grid",
        selected: true,
    },
    {
        name: TabItemType.SolarEnergy,
        title: "Solar Energy",
        icon: "k-i-calendar",
        selected: false,
    },
    { name: TabItemType.PowerUsage, title: "Power Usage", icon: "k-i-calendar" },
    { name: TabItemType.RateTabe, title: "Rate Table", icon: "k-i-calendar" },
    { name: TabItemType.Profile, title: "Profile", icon: "k-i-user" },
    { name: TabItemType.Info, title: "Info", icon: "k-i-information" },
    ];

    items.forEach((rec) => {
        console.log(rec.name);
    })
```

Now, I get an error saying

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'ItemType'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ separator: boolean; }'
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ0imB2CuC2wBUCGAjAkgF3LBBPADuMAN4BQYYAIkgM4AWKA9kgE4AmwAvMAESUCCAZQASAIQDy-AEqUeAGnIUQgxgBtWAUUjgWAc1xdeg8QBlpGgHIapAcQCa8xUoAKjAO46AqjSS6i3HmdxAHVrT0F+Gw1HJRApJCxkFH9eKX4EDQR+URNohVjgZxZGADMAS1UUwKlxADE0XJjYtEgSxkMeNAta8SalAF9SJwoMAiJMbDxCQ2IacHxWBMYWAC5gJjVwJEhgfuAAHxAyAsgkWHA1pImcMYBuYAwyjEq1mgwWMshde7KAY0ZIK93p9vsA5pVflg2AB+NYbSrbYZgQZI0D-SBvYBPbA0Nb8FgsJC4AA81ym4AAfIYANqoo50iinc6XVBksYAOmo9CYrDY+QKoEezwuvC5DGY7D6Ar+ALWPAA1gBaMqK3QfNhSgrg8CQ8BsNbvaDgfkDE0UY4CkBMkVXLA3QjslTqFhaHT6M0FIUvIxqVjAV16XCa2IywG8JUq35ISqQNisYNKbW6-XAErRuYe0D9TNHYDWlnoO3k9muDwsby+Y0PJ7ewLuHTACt+eRY9FyiOKqMxuMsHi7HMkPNnG2sosc+KJVBVr0ingTohJSot0Pt5Wd6NQHt97MM4hD5mIUeTDlFUoVac12en8pLuSt2XhtfQOa9-u7-cjwvHh0tNp3mdyr+jDLm2j4qp8bQsLACRlAC24DgAurcQwFNisA0OykEaEgvx0AAFHhLA6gAlFwVIWpa6I0Js7KqIwuiETq7LWsRyEFP0xFDEAA

Comment: You use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing), in this case probably an `in` style type guard. Details in the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined an item as

```
type ItemType = {separator: boolean } |  {
```

so you need to explicitly narrow out the possibility of the object being iterated over being a `separator` object first.

```
items.forEach((rec) => {
    if ('name' in rec) {
        console.log(rec.name);
    }
})
```

Either that, or remove the separators from the type:

```
type ItemType = {
    name: TabItemType; title: string; icon: string; selected?: boolean
}
```

Comment: 'name' in rec is exactly what I was looking for.  I feel like I should have been able to find that but googled and googled and googled.  Can you point me at the category of where that doc is describing that feature?

Comment: It's just type narrowing: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html